# Multiple Testing - FWER

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am confused about Family Wise Error Rate(FWER) when dealing with multiple testing. What would change about the FWER in the case of positively correlated p-values. For example if I perform independently 2 tests, and the p-values are not correlated then, FWER = 1 - (1-alpha)^2 (Right?), for some level alpha. 
But how would FWER change in the case where the p-values are positively correlated? How about in the case where the p-values are negatively correlated?

Any help would be appreciated! 
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean positively or negatively correlated p-values?

Comment: If the 2 tests that are performed are positively correlated - their p-values will be positively correlated, that is if one is small, then the other will tend to be small as well, and if one is large then the other will tend to be large. I maybe should consider the case when two events are dependent, and assuming the events (A and B) are the same. Then, P(A and B) = P(A and A) = P(A). If that is true, then following the way FWER is calculated I would get FWER = 1 - (1-alpha) = alpha.